# Android : Setting locale programmatically causes to google maps load custom marker icon from wrong drawable locale

Tags: android, google-maps, localization

I'm trying to change locale via a button for user,so i wrote this wrapper class to do it in a baseActivity which all of my activities inherits from,like this:

ContextWrapper.java

```
public class ContextWrapper extends android.content.ContextWrapper {

    public ContextWrapper(Context base) {
        super(base);
    }

    public static ContextWrapper wrap(Context context, Locale newLocale) {

        Resources res = context.getResources();
        Configuration configuration = res.getConfiguration();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            configuration.setLocale(newLocale);

            LocaleList localeList = new LocaleList(newLocale);
            LocaleList.setDefault(localeList);
            configuration.setLocales(localeList);

            context = context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);

        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            configuration.setLocale(newLocale);
            context = context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);

        } else {
            configuration.locale = newLocale;
            res.updateConfiguration(configuration, res.getDisplayMetrics());
        }

        return new ContextWrapper(context);
    }
}
```

and I use it in BaseActivity class like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        sharedpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(newBase);
        //getLang() is some method that loads a language tag like "en" or "fr" from sharedpreferences 
        String languageToLoad  = getLang(); // your language
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);

        Context context = ContextWrapper.wrap(newBase, locale);
        super.attachBaseContext(context);

    }
```

and I recreate my activity to changes takes effect and app will load new resources using:
        recreate();

All things works fine and all other resources loads from right locale till this line which I've google map in my activity(even google map language is right!):

```
        private Marker destinationMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(dstLatLng)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.dest_set)));
```

I've resource files with identical names `dest_set` in all of my localized resources(drawbles to be specific)

the problem is when I set marker from any choosen language it will only uses the drawbles with no localization(like `drawable-hdpi` , ... ) which i put "en" files as default,what's wrong with my code?

Comment: There may not be anything wrong with your code. Try loading the drawable into a `Bitmap` yourself, then using `fromBitmap()` instead of `fromResource()`. The output may not look quite right, but that's not the objective of the test. If you supply your own `Bitmap` from the resource, and it shows up with the language that you want, then my guess is that `fromResource()` is sending the resource ID over to Play Services, and Play Services is actually loading it. Play Services is a separate process and is unaffected by your locale change.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes,I can confirm that it does works,but the result is nasty! if map shows the right language(which is) why you think it shouldn't load the right resources trough play services(something doesn't match in this argument tough!)?is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

> I can confirm that it does works,but the result is nasty!

That part does not surprise me, though perhaps with some experimentation you could find a bitmap that works.

As I noted in my comment, my guess is to what's going on is that `BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource()` does not decode the resource in your process. It decodes the resource in Play Services' process. You have changed the locale in your process, but that does not affect Play Services, and so it loads the resource using the device's standard locale(s).

> is there any other way?

Off the cuff, your choices are:

1. Find some approach using `fromBitmap()` that works, or otherwise have the resource-decoding step be done in your process, so your process' locale (not Play Services') is the one that is used.
2. Use something else, other than `fromBitmap()` or `fromResource()`, where you control the bitmap contents. For example, you could put these images in `assets/`, with paths in there tied to their locales, then try `fromAsset()`.
3. Discontinue your locale-changing feature.
4. Discontinue your map-markers feature.

Comment: there are another ways(I refer to them as bad practices of course),such as using a if/else condition to check the language then set the marker with a different drawable name for each language,...
in my journey to find a proper solution, i've found some apps that even changes the language of google fuse location api for asking turn on the gps via a dialog at application level,we definitely are missing sth.

Comment: @A.R.H: "then set the marker with a different drawable name for each language" -- I was thinking of that when writing the answer, then forgot to include it, my apologies. :-( You can use resource aliases to help here, I think, so the same image is referred to by different names.